# Testng && Spring context unit test -> execute sql before and after test method

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng

When using JUnit a SpringRunner, there is an awesome feature of executing scripts before and after any test method

```
@Test
    @SqlGroup([
            @Sql(scripts = ["classpath:clean_db.sql", "populate_data.sql"]),
            @Sql(scripts = ["classpath:clean_db.sql"], executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
    ])
```

However, when using testngframework and running spring-context tests, this annotation doesn't work because testng uses AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests instead of SpringRunner

Is there any similar annotation in testng or any other util to execute scripts before and after tests?

Comment: That should also work with TestNG it isn't tied to a framwork as it is executed by a `TestExecutionListener` which works transparantly in both TestNG and JUnit.

Comment: Does clean_db.sql simply drops all tables? If so, it can be replaced with `@DirtiesContext(classMode= DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)`. And populateDb.sql can be runned in `@Before` method

Comment: Not sure @DirtiesContext() will help here. sql is executed against a real oracle, not an embedded h2

Comment: However, it does not work with testng, which is strange, because AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests is a class of Spring and @SqlGroup is an annotation of Spring. I guess, I'll need to provide a simple github sample project

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why executing the script in the TestNG annotations @AfterTest or @AfterMethod (depending what you need) wouldn't work?

The first one would run after all the tests under a suite run, and the second, after each test method.

Comment: There might be some cases where I don't want to run script after each method. But practically speaking, BeforeMethod and AfterMethod will probably be fine.

However, I'll still need some helper method to run the script

Comment: You can use a flag to determine in each method if you want to run the script in the @AfterMethod method. But yes, I think you will need a helper for that query.

Comment: Whole point of annotations is declarative =) manual script execution, especially with some flag stinks sooo much!